# Mapping from One Sheet to Another Fill Unfilled chracter

Tags: excel, printing, header, mapping, vba

So I have one excel document that has partially filled character array ("|" shows excel column line):

[image: Screenshot of Excel]

**Current Result ("_" is a space):**

```
1111GGH80100022190
1112QQH80100023201
1113GGH80100045201
1114AAH80100025190
```

So my current code outputs this above result. The problem is that characters **1-5** and **21-24** get skipped over. In general if there is no column number accounted for I should print " " (Space).

**Desired Result ("_" is a space):**

```
_____1111GGH80100022____190
_____1112QQH80100023____201
_____1113GGH80100045____201
_____1114AAH80100025____190
```

Is there are column way to detect if I am missing a range in the header column? I currently use this and only select the data:

```
Private Sub WriteFile_Click()
Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, I As Integer, j As Integer

myFile = "C:\Reformatted.txt"
Set rng = Selection

Open myFile For Output As #1

For I = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count

cellValue = cellValue + CStr(rng.Cells(I, j).Value)
cellValue = Replace(cellValue, "NULL", "    ")

If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
    Print #1, cellValue
End If

    Next j
    cellValue = ""
Next I

Close #1
Shell "C:\Windows\Notepad.exe C:\Reformatted.txt", 1
End Sub
```

-----------------------------After TMh885 Answer--------------------------------

So the code works perfectly EXCEPT if you have a header thats a single number '63'

So I am trying this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, I As Integer, j As Integer

myFile = "C:\Reformatted.txt"
Set rng = Selection

Open myFile For Output As #1

Dim strArr(1 To 63) As String, intBeg As Integer, intEnd As Integer, intCount As Integer

For I = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        If Len(Cells) = 1 Then
            cellValue = cellValue + " "
        Else
            intBeg = Val(Left(Cells(1, j).Value, InStr(1, Cells(1, j).Value, "-") - 1))
            intEnd = Val(Right(Cells(1, j).Value, Len(Cells(1, j).Value) - InStr(1, Cells(1, j).Value, "-")))
            intCount = 1
            For t = intBeg To intEnd
                strArr(t) = Mid(Cells(I, j).Value, intCount, 1)
                intCount = intCount + 1
            Next t
        End If

    Next j
    For t = 1 To UBound(strArr)
        If strArr(t) = "" Then strArr(t) = " "
        cellValue = cellValue + strArr(t)
    Next t
    Erase strArr
    Print #1, cellValue
    cellValue = ""
Next I
Close #1
Shell "C:\Windows\Notepad.exe C:\Reformatted.txt", 1

End Sub
```

--------------------------------Error Snapshot----------------------------------

Input:

[image]

Comment: Is it safe to assume that each number in the header corresponds to one character?

Comment: Could you clear up the beggining of your question? I don't see characters 1-5 in what you wrote. I don't understand what you are trying to do at all.

Comment: @DavidGM and TMH885
I added a screenshot and more thorough results for clarity. Thanks again for the time!

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do. I just don't understand what the problem IS. What do you mean by 1-5 being skipped? Also what does this sentence mean: Is there are column way to detect if I am missing a range in the header column?

Comment: @TMH8885 and DavidGM I clarified the current and the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code with the extra functionality built in.  It essentially just builds an array, adds each character to the correct location then adds it all together, replacing blanks with spaces.  You'll have to change the maximum (in this example it's hard-coded at 27) but you could use the same logic as I used to get "intEnd" to find your maximum by looping over the heading column.  Notes, this will compensate for out of order columns and I assumed that the Selection includes headers (hence starting at I = 2):

```
Private Sub WriteFile_Click()
Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, I As Integer, j As Integer

myFile = "C:\Reformatted.txt"
Set rng = Selection

Open myFile For Output As #1

Dim strArr(1 To 27) As String, intBeg As Integer, intEnd As Integer, intCount As Integer

For I = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        If InStr(1, CStr(Cells(1, j).Value), "-") = 0 Then
            strArr(Val(Cells(1, j).Value)) = Cells(I, j).Value
        Else
            intBeg = Val(Left(Cells(1, j).Value, InStr(1, Cells(1, j).Value, "-") - 1))
            intEnd = Val(Right(Cells(1, j).Value, Len(Cells(1, j).Value) - InStr(1, Cells(1, j).Value, "-")))
            intCount = 1
            For t = intBeg To intEnd
                strArr(t) = Mid(Cells(I, j).Value, intCount, 1)
                intCount = intCount + 1
            Next t
        End If
    Next j
    For t = 1 To UBound(strArr)
        If strArr(t) = "" Then strArr(t) = " "
        cellValue = cellValue + strArr(t)
    Next t
    Erase strArr
    Print #1, cellValue
    cellValue = ""
Next I
Close #1
Shell "C:\Windows\Notepad.exe C:\Reformatted.txt", 1
End Sub
```

Comment: This is GREAT! Thanks a lot! One quick clarification: How to work with only 1 header number? As I understand your code works with finding intBeg (25) and int End(27), but what if the header is one number 63? I tried a Len() if loop. Check my posted code.

Comment: I'd use an IF statement, I'll edit in a possibility into my answer.

Comment: Ah I see. Where to put the end if?

Comment: The line before `Next j`

Comment: So it returns this error: "Runtime Error 9" Subscription out of range.
Debug: "strArr(t) = Mid(Cells(I, j).Value, intCount, 1)"    I mean you've helped a bunch but if you could help here that'd be great! :)

Comment: Can you tell me what the input(header/field) was that threw this error?  Was it formatted as a number?  This is outside of the IF checking for a one number header, so it should still work.

Comment: I included a snapshot of the input and if you want the error snapshot I can do that as well.

Comment: Did you change the Maximum (in the `Dim strArr(1 to 27)`)  27 to 63?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80806/discussion-between-dasman-and-tmh8885).